# How do multi-touch gestures in iOS behave if more than 2 fingers are involved?

Tags: ios, flash, multi-touch, gesture

I'm developing a multi-touch library for Flash and not to reinvent all the wheels I try to check how other developers code similar stuff. One of the biggest problems is gestures with multiple fingers involved (more than 2). The gestures in question are pan(move), pinch(zoom/scale) and rotate.

It's not obvious how these gestures should behave with more than 2 fingers at all. Looking at Photos app on iPad I see that photos react on first two touches only. And if you press one finger, press another finger, press the third thinger and remove the first finger -- zoom gesture will stop working even if you have (and indeed you do) 2 fingers touching same photo. That doesn't seem logical.

What I'm trying to do is to break points into 2 clusters and work with them. But it brings more unresolved problems.

So, the question is the following: How do multi-touch gestures in iOS behave if more than 2 fingers are involved? Is there any guideline or everyone implements whatever they feel like doing?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  How do they behave?  The same way any gesture "behaves".  If you decide a 4-finger tap will turn the screen blue (and implement it), then that's how it behaves.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it really depends on the version of the OS the device is running.  Multi-touch Events are being improved constantly

If you really want to see how other people are doing this with flash download the [Open Exibits API](http://openexhibits.org/software/sdk).  It's a really nice library that should show you how other people have handled the multi-touch across different devices.

As far as behavior goes though each touch point is treated as a single touch point.  So each touch point is monitored the same way.  Touch point one is no different than touch point five.

Multi-touch "gestures" are fired by the OS and the OS only.  It would be stupid to create a library of multi-touch "questures" when the OS already has them and they are better than the ones you could try and create as a third party.  However if you are trying to create custom gestures good luck, when I was at a conference in Minneapolis they said you're better off using the built in ones.